# How to create history of all pdf file clicked by user?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[This is what I want for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ayfw.jpg)

I am stuck at passing my recycler view to  the recent tab or you can say history tab...
I have created the pdf app in android studio everything is working fine but the problem that i m facing is i dont know how to add the same recycler view item from one tab(docs tab) to other tab(history) whenever i  click on my pdf file.
I want to replace the file in history tab if already present in history list and add it to the 0 position of the history tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1- To basically just always show one recyclerView but update the items sorting whenever the top buttons are clicked.

2- To load 2 fragments for each tab which both have the same items but different sorting.

None of them are really hard especially 2. Just do a basic tab layout (lots of tutorials for it on YouTube) and in each fragment just use a different sorting function. For doing 1, you should use DiffUtils to update your list beautifully and fast.

Although I am not sure which part you are having a hard time with. Doing two tabs, updating the recyclerView, or remembering which files were opened last?!

Comment: I dont have problem with making tab layout the only problem is that i want to share the recycler view whenever the user click pdf file that is in document tab  to my history tab and whenever the user click again on that same pdf file in documents tab it should come again at the first position of the history tab if it is already present at some position for example it might be present in history tab at 4 position and now when the user click on that pdf file it will come to the first position.

Comment: You cannot really share the same recyclerView in two fragments. You have to just use two different ones. You can put most of the code in the activity and just send the final PDF list to the fragments so you just load PDF files once. Then just sort them differently on each fragment. Alsolook into DiffUtils for updating your recyclerViews.